# Android Gradle 3.0.0 - add library dependency for specific flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

My app includes a library and a 3 flavor debug, release and custom.
I don't want my app to include the library in 'custom' flavor 
Prior to gradle 3.0 I used :

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':myLib', configuration: "release")  
debugCompile project(path: ':..:myLib', configuration: "debug")  
// 'custom' ignored
```

according to google [migrate to android plugin for 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#resolve_matching_errors) I need to use implementation keyword with matchingFallbacks for 'custom' flavor.

I don't want to use 'matchingFallbacks' because I don't want my app to include the lib in 'custom' flavor.

Any idea how can I compile the lib only in debug and release?

*edit*

maybe its possible to add 'if' statement i.e:

```
if(flavor != custom){ 
    implementation project 'myLib' 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by using something like this:

```
dependencies {
   // use only mylib for debug and release
   releaseImplementation project(path: ':mylib')
   debugImplementation project(path: ':mylib')

   // this will be used by all the flavor
   implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

Comment: yes that solve my problem . thanks !   I need to remove the ' configuration: "release"'  and 'configuration: "debug" ' from 'releaseImplementation '

Comment: Great! Glad it help you!